# How can I make a flat, spiralled surface?

Tags: modeling

I'm a bit new to Blender so I apologize if this is a really simple thing.
I'm trying to make a peppermint candy in Blender (like this:

[image: this],

one of those red ones that looks swirled. So I'm extruding a circle, slightly rounding the edge, then there's a flat surface, and there are equal cuts of the disc that alternate red and white. Is there a way to basically twist the whole thing around the centerpoint such that the bands curve like that?
Thanks very much!

Comment: Look up proportional editing

Comment: I've used proportional editing for some simple resizing/reshaping...I guess I don't quite see how it would be used for this problem. Would I use it with a rotation?

Comment: Yes, that would be the way to do this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- In *Object Mode* add <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> a circle (Mesh/Circle)
  [image: Set]
- Change to *Edit Mode* Tab make sure you're in vertex select mode.
- Extrude and Scale <kbd>E</kbd>,<kbd>S</kbd>,<kbd>0</kbd>
- Change to Face select (see image below)
- Click a random face, select all <kbd>A</kbd>
- From the menu pick *Select/ Checker Deselect*

[image]

- Create another material and assign it to the selection
- Add loop cuts <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> <kbd>RMB</kbd>
  [image]
- With the inner faces select you're there
- Set proprtional editing <kbd>O</kbd> and rotate <kbd>R</kbd>
  [image]

You might want to select the outer edges and extrude them to add the on colored border as in the reference image.

Result with some tweaking:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Oh, awesome. This is incredibly helpful! Thanks very much!